# Converting from cert8.db to PEM

Tags: ssl-certificate, pem, pkcs#12

I am having a cert8.db in /home/hari/Desktop/certs directory. Now I want to convert this into PEM.  tried to do this by first trying to export the cert8.db in pkcs12 to pem using pkutil

```
pk12util -o cert.pem -n cert8.db -d /home/hari/Desktop/certs
```

However this throws an error

```
pk12util: function failed: security library: bad database.
```

I have no idea what's going wrong here. Please help me out with it. Also any suggestions on alternative ways of doing this would also be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have figured it out by now, that the file belongs to Mozilla Firefox 4.x - security database. On Windows 7 Pro this is stored on the system root for some odd reason, that causes my security software to go nuts...

Then again, you might not have Firefox installed in your env.